# use python to get k8s node status

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes

I want to write a python script that will give me the name of the k8s cluster node and the status of the nodes.
I was thinking of using somehow `kubectl get nodes` command and then text processing commands like awk to get the nice output like:
`$node_name has $status_value`
where node_name and status value will be substituted with actual values got from the script.

Comment: (a) `kubectl` can output JSON, which is easy to parse in Python; no need for `awk` or other tools. (b) k8s has an API which you can access directly from Python. (c) we generally expect you to make some attempt to solve the problem yourself first before posting here, although Joel seems to be feeling generous today.

Comment: @larsks thank you for the recommendations, I thought of writing my attempts but there were just so wrong that I wanted to start with a question like is this even possible to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Kubernetes Python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) to list nodes and process them.

Here is a list of APIs that the client library covers. It sounds like you would want to use the list node API:

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/README.md

Once the library is installed and imported, this snippet should list the nodes:

```
k8s_api = client.CoreV1Api()
logger.info("Getting k8s nodes...")
response = k8s_api.list_node()
```

Comment: thanks Joel, I am trying to get your suggestion implemented as my solution, currently I'm fighting with importing module. 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "node-stats.py", line 4, in <module>
    from kubernetes.client import list_node
ImportError: cannot import name 'list_node' from 'kubernetes.client' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/kubernetes/client/__init__.py)`
I used instructions from provided link, running both commands:
`pip install git+https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python.git`
`sudo pip install git+https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python.git`

Comment: A couple of quick questions to check: Do you have both python 2.7 and 3.x installed on the machine? Are you sure that pip install actually installed your dependency? Depending on how your path is set up, did you use pip, or pip3? How to install a python dependency is probably a separate question.

Comment: I am using pyhton3 and I followed instructions from the GitHub link you've provided, I managed to get this working once I set the right path. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to hear it @pia

Comment: BTW, if you are using AKS for your kuberentes, you'll need to monkeypatch the API to make this work https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/895